# Urllib Standard Library is not retrieving anything on Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib, ubuntu-16.04

Here is my code(on python 2.7)

```
import urllib
f_hand=urllib.urlopen('http://www.dr-chuck.com/page1.htm')
for line in f_hand:
    print line.strip()
```

And then when I tried to run it, it did not **retrieve anything** even after waiting for a long time, in spite of having a stable Internet Connection, but did **not show any error**.

When I force stopped it after waiting for approx 1 hour, it gave the following tracebacks:

[image: Screenshot of terminal output]

I am working on Ubuntu 16.04

**Even tried it on ideone**

Comment: The Screen shot was mistakenly uploaded, the correct one is :https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwDkPBmJ4q3CbDVpMWJXQll6OFU

Comment: Uploaded wrong Picture of the Output Terminal, the Correct one is [link]https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwDkPBmJ4q3CbDVpMWJXQll6OFU

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue,  most likely the issue is not directly related to python but your own network, can you curl to  url?

Comment: Were you able to open `http://www.dr-chuck.com/page1.htm` on your web browser?

Comment: Yes I was able to curl to my URL

Comment: Remove all the `proxy` which you use in college. urllib, httplib, requests uses proxy automatically if it's in your environment variable. Files you can check : `/etc/environment` and `~/.bashrc`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes even I was not able to curl the page. I think it is due to unstable Internet Connection.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to unstable Internet Connection particularly due to the use of Mobile WIFI/Dongle Service. The Code Works fine, when tried with Broadband(more stable) connectivity.